# WPF Clickable button under label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, wpf-controls

I have button. I have expander in button and label above expander in the same button.
I can click on button with no problem, but there is problem where I click on label (Nothing happens). How can I make this: When user clicks on label in button, button is being clicked. I want to transfer click event from label to button that contains that label.

```
<Button>
  <Label />
  <Expander>
  </Expander>
</Button>
```

**I want to be able to click button through label.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This change should make your label pass through clicks to the underlying control:

```
<Button>
  <Label IsHitTestVisible="False" />
  <Expander>
  </Expander>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bubble up the event using `RoutingStrategy.Bubble`. Here is a starter on routed events -> [Routed events](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/BeginWPF3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also force a click event to be triggered for the button that the label is inside of by placing the following code in the eventhandler of the label.

```
((Button)label1.Parent).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
```